# Want to write for a blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

One of the most important, and hardest, tasks for a new beta site is to get more members. A blog could be a great way to evangelize our nice, little site while getting more members and increasing participation.

Our blog obviously be about the Raspberry Pi. Topics such as the following.

1. Introductions/How To's
2. Projects involving the Raspberry Pi
3. Anything else you can imagine!

If you are interested in writing an article for our community blog leave an answer below with the following information.

1. [Your Trello username](https://trello.com/)
2. What you would be interested in writing about.

Don't worry if you don't have a lot of time to write articles. This blog **is not a permanent commitment**. Feel free to write articles whenever you feel like it and/or have time.

Comment: I still think it is too early for a blog.

Comment: Really? I think a blog would get new visitors interested in our site and make them more likely to create accounts and participate.