# Blog for the RaspberryPi

Tags: feature-request, blog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Want to write for a blog?](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210/want-to-write-for-a-blog)

I am putting this question soliciting opinions and interest from the communicty about having a community blog for the RaspberryPi.SE as mentioned [here](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/).

A blog might be a good place to showcase ones work which does not fit the QA format.